# UWP MapBillboard : Zooming Causes Fading and Invisibility

Tags: dictionary, uwp, bing

I am struggling with the UWP MapBillboard.  My goal is to overlay a geographical area (in this case the SE quarter of the United States) with an image from another source showing specific polygons over the same area, with lots of transparency outside those polygons.  My challenge is probably with the MapCamera.

I start off at a zoom level (approximately 4.0) and apply the billboard.  But as I zoom in, it starts to fade and once the image gets extended beyond the viewable area, it just disappears.

```
        BasicGeoposition billboardLocationse = new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = 38.3,
            Longitude = -92.0,
            Altitude = 0
        };

        MapCamera semapCamera = new MapCamera(new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
          { 
            Altitude = 0,
            Latitude = 38.3,
            Longitude = 92.00 
          },
          AltitudeReferenceSystem.Geoid)
         );

       // MapBillboard mapBillboardse = new MapBillboard(_mapControl.ActualCamera);
        MapBillboard mapBillboardse = new MapBillboard(semapCamera);

        mapBillboardse.CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible;
        mapBillboardse.Location = new Geopoint(billboardLocationse);
        mapBillboardse.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0);
        mapBillboardse.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Maps/overlay.png"));
        mapBillboardse.ZIndex = 1;
        _mapControl.MapElements.Add(mapBillboardse);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-an-image) even shows the problem of zooming causing fading.

How do I best position it essentially flat on the map, independent of the actual zoom area, sized within the same geo-boundaries and able to be seen at all zoom levels with no change in opacity?

Comment: Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapbillboard?view=winrt-19041) of MapBillboard, it mentions **"Displays an image that scales and fades in relation to its distance from the ReferenceCamera of the MapBillboard"**. So it is by design. If you want to always the image in all zoom levels and do not change transparency, maybe you could try to use MapIcon to display an image.

Comment: I have read that.  What I don't understand is how to define the ReferenceCamera that would set it at the right zoom level or altitude.  This would scale correctly where a MapIcon would stay the same visible size and would not adjust.

Comment: Do you mean you want to define a ReferenceCamera and apply it to the MapBillboard to always show the MapBillboard in all zoom levels and do not change transparency and its size?

Comment: Let me phrase it this way.  I want to overlay a MapBillboard across the entire United States from all 4 corners beginning at a zoom level of 4, which is about right to show.  

Then I want to be able to zoom down to any state and still be able to see the overlay section that is also being zoomed in on.  If I zoomed into Kansas, the overlay should not be seen in its entirety, but only the portion that was seen over Kansas at the initial level.

I am only hypothesizing that putting a specific Map Camera would do the trick.  Yet there might be a better way if one can be suggested.